# I am getting a defined error even though everything seems to be fine

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\botid.py", line 23, in <module>
    fiList = {msg:submission.ups + len(coList)}
NameError: name 'coList' is not defined
```

for this:

```
wbcWords = ['wbc', 'advice', 'prc','server']
while True:
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit('MCPE')
    for submission in subreddit.get_hot(limit=30):
        op_text = submission.title.lower()
        has_wbc = any(string in op_text for string in wbcWords)
        # Test if it contains a WBC-related question
        if submission.id not in already_done and has_wbc:
            msg = '[WBC related thread](%s)' % submission.short_link
            comments = submission.comments
            for comment in comments:
                coList = [comment.author.name]
            fiList = {msg:submission.ups + len(coList)}
            print fiList
```

Seems fine to me. All the search results end up being spelling mistakes, but mine seems fine (I hope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try:

```
coList = []
for comment in comments:
    coList.append(comment.author.name)
```

What you were trying with:

```
for comment in comments:
    coList = [comment.author.name]
```

For every comment this loop is resetting colList to a single item list of the current comments author name, but I can see from your comment you have understood that.

The other comments with list comprehension are much nicer imo, personally I would also use:

```
colist = [comment.author.name for comment in comments]
```

Looks cleaner its one line and you can clearly read what the intent is, a list of the authors in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution would be a list comprehension:

```
coList = [comment.author.name for comment in comments]
```

This way, if comments is empty, you get an empty list, otherwise the author names. Additionally, given what you put in, it's better to call it `authors_list`.

Answer (score 0):

coList is only being defined if comments is non-empty. If comments is empty then coList will never be defined, hence the resulting name error.

It also looks like you are re-defining coList in every iteration of the loop, but it looks likely that you actually want to be appending to it?

Comment: Ah no, it's supposed to check it just once, but that's no biggy. I tried defining it before the for loop but I still get the same error.